# How to display user info after logging in in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is for my project and i am seeking help because I found difficulty in my `ViewProfile` page in MVC ASP.NET.

I have successfully used FormsAuthentication so that I can display my name after logging in, but i have created a link for `ViewProfile` where I can display my details from registering that can be acquired from the database. But I cannot make that work. can someone please help me solve this problem.

I am not using EntityFramework, btw...

Comment: >I have successfully used formsauthentication so that I can display my name after loggin in. but i have created a link for ViewProfile where I can display my details from registering that can be acquired from the database. But I cannot make that work.     What's not working ?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the information by using this code

```
 ////  // Instantiate the ASP.NET Identity system
            var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
            var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());


            // Recover the profile information about the logged in user

            ViewBag.description = currentUser.UserName;
```

and in your view

```
<h3>@ViewBag.description</h3>
```

you have to use the usermanager this worked for me but remember this only displays the info.